# Updating a value without banging

Tags: puredata

I am new to pure data, and I am attempting to build a small sampler.  I have a message called "active-track", that controls what track you are currently recording into.  When recording into a track, I want to mute the old recording.  I have a message called "track1-vol", and I want to update that to 0, but I need to know what track to mute to do that.  How would I keep track of what the current track is without muting the active track whenever it is updated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be a better fit for stackoverflow, rather than here. It would appear to be a pure coding question, not related to 'sound' itself.

Comment: PD is a graphical signal processing and sound design tool.